# Replace switches with Implements

Tags: java

I am trying to replace every case operator with separate class which will implements method from case. But I did something wrong. As always:D I am getting NullPointerException. I think the problem is in the interface, but I am asking you te be sure.

There's class with switch:

```
public class RSSFeedParser {
private static final String TITLE = "title";
private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String LANGUAGE = "language";
private static final String COPYRIGHT = "copyright";
private static final String LINK = "link";
private static final String AUTHOR = "author";
private static final String ITEM = "item";
private static final String PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
private static final String GUID = "guid";
private static String description = "";
private static String title = "";
private static String link = "";
private static String language = "";
private static String copyright = "";
private static String author = "";
private static String pubDate = "";
private static String guid = "";
private Feed feed = null;

public InputStream in;
private XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
private XMLEventReader eventReader;


final URL url;

public RSSFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
    try {
        url = new URL(feedUrl);
        in = read();
        eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);
        read().close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public Feed readFeed() {
    try {
        boolean isFeedHeader = true;
        while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                String localPart = event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();
                switch (localPart) {
                    case ITEM:
                        if (isFeedHeader) {
                            isFeedHeader = false;
                            feed = new Feed(title, link, description, language, copyright, pubDate);
                        }
                        event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                        break;
                    case TITLE:
                        title = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                    case DESCRIPTION:
                        description = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                    case LINK:
                        link = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                    case GUID:
                        guid = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                    case LANGUAGE:
                        language = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                    case AUTHOR:
                        author = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                    case PUB_DATE:
                        pubDate = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                    case COPYRIGHT:
                        copyright = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                        eventReader.close();
                        break;
                }
                eventReader.close();
            } else if (event.isEndElement()) {
                if (event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart() == (ITEM)) {
                    setAllElements();
                }
            }
```

And I have done:

```
public class RSSFeedParser {


public static final String ITEM = "item";
public static String description = "";
public static String title = "";
public static String link = "";
public static String language = "";
public static String copyright = "";
public static String author = "";
public static String pubDate = "";
public static String guid = "";
public Feed feed;
public boolean isFeedHeader;
TITLE tytul = new TITLE();
AUTHOR autor =  new AUTHOR();
COPYRIGHT prawa = new COPYRIGHT();
DESCRIPTION opis = new DESCRIPTION();
GUID identyfikacja = new GUID();
LANGUAGE jezyk = new LANGUAGE();
LINK linskon = new LINK();
PUB_DATE publikajca = new PUB_DATE();
ITEM itemson = new ITEM();

public InputStream in;
public XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
public XMLEventReader eventReader;
public  XMLEvent event;

final URL url;

public RSSFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
    try {
        url = new URL(feedUrl);
        in = read();
        eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);
        event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public Feed readFeed() throws XMLStreamException {
    try {
        isFeedHeader = true;
            while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
            itemson.feedData();
            tytul.feedData();
            opis.feedData();
            linskon.feedData();
            identyfikacja.feedData();
            jezyk.feedData();
            autor.feedData();
            publikajca.feedData();
            prawa.feedData();
            eventReader.close();
        }


    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return feed;}
```

And interface:

```
public interface Case {
RSSFeedParser rss = null; // the reason why I get NullPointerException, right? But how else could I get into the fields of the this class without constructing its object?
void feedData() throws XMLStreamException;
```

One of few classes:

```
public class COPYRIGHT implements Case {
@Override
public void feedData() throws XMLStreamException {
    rss.copyright = rss.getCharacterData(rss.event, rss.eventReader);
    rss.eventReader.close();
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ITEM.feedData(ITEM.java:9)
>       at RSSFeedParser.readFeed(RSSFeedParser.java:61)
>       at ReadTest.printRSS(ReadTest.java:70)
>       at ReadTest.MENU(ReadTest.java:33)
>       at ReadTest.main(ReadTest.java:16)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Comment: So yes, that *is* the reason you're getting the NPE, but I suspect something else is going on here.  The variable declared in the interface is ***not*** the same as a variable declared in even an abstract class.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. What do you mean? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: So, a field on an interface is always implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`; you can't change its value now that it's set to `null`.  You can't (and shouldn't ever consider) store(-e+ing) state in an interface.

Comment: now i get it. https://github.com/Sh4rk1/sh4rk1  - there's a whole program with every class. I will also paste an error massage below.

Comment: @M4rk1, you are correct the `rss` declaration inside interface is part of NPE problem. It is null because you never assign an instance into it. It is not good idea to define property in interface because it makes the property static final. You either pass on `RSSFeedParser` into concrete `Case` classes constructor, or define `setRSSFeedParser` in the interface.

Comment: @DJ but RSSFeedParser as the default constructor takes String. so how I should write this setter?

Comment: On different note, it is a good idea that you are thinking of streamlining your code with polymorphism; however your logic won't work because the switch case only read of the stream in 1 case, while your _refactor_ code each implementation of `Case` will read from the stream.

Comment: The constructor option that I meant is: 1. Create constructor for each `Case` implementation that takes `RSSFeedParser`. 2. Move all `Case`(s) instantiation inside `RSSFeedParser`'s constructor. 3. Instantiate them by passing itself: `tytul = new TITLE(this); autor = new AUTHOR(this);`